# mapView should not be draggable if stretched/pinched

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a mapView inside my fragment, when it is zoomed i.e pinched or stretched the map should not get dragged it should only do the zoom operation. I tried mapView.setOnTouchListener() but it is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
mapView.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you @arbaz but it should not affect the zoom in/out, this will disable zoom in/out control too.

Comment: Please refer the below link and override all methods except zoom and pinch

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/DefaultMapViewOnTouchListener.html